# React redux store issues

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am attempting to pull variables from my backend and store them in the frontend. I have react and redux and the piping is setup but I am having trouble with how to store the variable for access later or accessing the Redux store in other places. I am using these variables as URL endpoints (i.e. for changing servers, etc.) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me what you are asking is "how to use redux" which is probably best answered by reading the docs. The redux docs use a fairly good example to walk you through the functionality.

Comment: We need some sample code to actually figure out how you've got things set up. There are a few different ways to "set up" redux as well as different or custom middleware. Please add parts of your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Contexts and do something like this:

`const MyVariablesContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);`

For the defaultValue you can use an Immutable Object or Make an API/Server call and populate the values. Once they are populated you can use React Provider API to consume it.

You can look into how to use React contexts here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context

If you could give more context in your questions it would be better. But if you are using `recompose` then `withContext` HOC is what an ideal solution would be.

Comment: In my code, what I'm doing is making an API call in a class called CommonApi to get the URLs needed for my application. Following that, I need to access CommonApi in other API calls in order to access the right place. The issue I'm having trouble is that I am getting a promise in return when I make the API call in CommonApi and that doesn't really let me access the URL value I want. Where the API classes are not react components.

Comment: If you share some of your code it would be better to understand. I am little confused over whether you are finding it difficult to access the values returned by the promise or is it something to do with Redux here.